# incorrect lines display in ssh console

Tags: debian, console, display

I have problem with my console drawing lines. The problem is when I connect through ssh to server everything draws ok. But when I use up arrow key to show last used commands it often leaves few characters after `$` sign:

```
user@host:~$ cd /var/www_vhosts/
user@host:/var/www_vhosts$ ls -la instalator-paczek/
razem 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 root        root       4096 02-20 10:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root        root       4096 05-17 11:11 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 root        developers 3380 05-29 11:03 instalator-paczek.sh
drwxrwxr-x  2 user developers 4096 05-29 11:03 logi
user@host:/var/www_vhosts$ cd instalator-paczek/
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ nano instalator-paczek.sh 
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ cp -r inst
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ nano /etc/issue
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ uname
Linux
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ uname -a
Linux host 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l
# here I use up arrow key to display last used commands and everything is ok until it show last: "cp -r in..." command
# "cp -r inst" is shown and next last used commands are shown after those 10 characters. I displays them like:
# $ cp -r instls -la
# $ cp -r instcd directory 
# etc.
# I tried using backspace but it clear characters just until "cp -r inst", not even one more
# prompt is shown correctly only after i press enter or ^C
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ cp -r instnano /etc/issue 
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ ls
instalator-paczek.sh  logi
```

What is even more irritating is what happens when I type more characters than console width. Cursor somehow goes back to the beginning of line and overwrites prompt:

```
/d/asd/as/d/asd/asd/as/d/asd/asdww_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ ls -la asdkasdasdasd/asdasdasd/asdasdasdasdasdas/dasdsdaas/d/asd/as/d/asd/as
```

I can't use any long commands because it overwrites beginning and I can't see if I typed everything correctly. Long command when pasted inside console works even if display is corrupted. It's like only display is corrupted but command itself is ok.

I have ubuntu 12.10 and use `Konsole` as console application. On server there is `Debian GNU Linux 6.0` and xterm.

```
user@host:/var/www_vhosts/instalator-paczek$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

It only happens with this server other servers I connect works good with `Konsole`.

How to fix this?

#### EDIT

Is this possible that those errors are occurring because there is no `xterm` installed on server and there is no resize command?

```
user@host:~$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 57; columns 151; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
user@host:~$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 57; columns 172; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

It seems like resizing console window also changes `stty`.

**EDIT2**

I've installed `xterm` package on server. I've logged out and log in again but problem is still the same. Should I restart server after installing `xterm` or something?

**EDIT3**

Solution [here](https://serverfault.com/a/514497/97723)

Comment: although I am not sure, when you connect by ssh what kind of terminal do you have?
I'm using TERM=xterm when connecting by ssh and I don't see that problem

Comment: @AlexandreAlves I'm also using `xterm`. I updated my question

Comment: What distro is the server you're remoting into?

Comment: @slm it's `Debian GNU Linux 6.0`, I've updated my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @slm I know but I'm not sysadmin on server so I would prefer not to install xterm if possible because it also wants install some drivers like: `libdrm-intel1 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libice6 libsm6 libutempter0 libxaw7 libxcb-atom1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxmu6
  libxpm4 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 x11-utils xbitmaps`. Is there other way? Maybe use something that is already installed, other than xterm. I also saw that resizing console windows also changes `stty` settings correctly. See my edit.

Comment: Without `xterm` resizing is not an option on the remote side. What about if you run `resize` on your local system prior to logging into the server? Does that help?

Comment: @slm resize on my side and `stty sane` didn't work. I'll try to install `xterm` tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I found solution. The problem was that `$PS1` didn't have color sequences enclosed with `\[` and `\]`. Before correcting `$PS1` was:

```
export PS1='\e[1;32m\u@\h:\w$ \e[m'
```

after fix:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h:\w$ \[\e[m\]'
```

I found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024884/commandline-overwrites-itself-when-the-commands-get-to-long

Answer (score 4):

After connecting to the remote server I would try running the command `resize`.  This will set the terminal settings the the current window size.

Additionally you can use the command `reset`, if your terminal appears to be left in an abnormal state. This will revert your terminal to a known good state.

You can read up on both these commands in their man pages.

- [resize man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/resize)
- [reset man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset)

#### resize command missing

The `resize` command is part of the xterm package so if this isn't installed then this command won't be available.

#### Additional things to try

If neither of the above commands work or are available you many be able to reset your stty terminal by using the command `stty sane`.

Comment: There is no resize command on server. Reset is also not working :(

Comment: I've installed xterm on server logged out and log in again but problem is the same. Do I need to restart server to make `xterm` working?